# How to receive collection with and without nullable objects in kotlin keeping the reference same

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, collections

In Kotlin, I have `MutableList<Something> noNulls = ...` and `MutableList<Something?> nullsInBetween = ...`

How can I write a method in kotlin which can accept both of these types while holding the same reference?

```
fun removeFirstElementFromList(theList:MutableList<Something?>){
  theList.remove(0)
}
```

this will not work for the list *noNulls*.

(In java it would be simply `removeFirstElementFromList(List<Something> theList)`, which works for both the cases )

---

Continuing the question Can I type cast a `List<Something?> original` to `MutableList<Something?>` while holding same reference to original list in kotlin? (assuming original instance is mutable, but assigned to List<>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the type of the list, you can use `*` projection:

```
fun removeFirstElementFromList(theList:MutableList<*>){
  theList.removeAt(0)
}
```

If you need to add to the list, you can make it contravariant:

```
fun addElementToList(theList:MutableList<in Something>){
  theList.add(Something())
}
```

If you need to retrieve from the list, you can make it covariant:

```
fun callFooOnFirstItemOfList(theList:MutableList<out Something?>){
  theList.firstOrNull()?.foo()
}
```

If you need to pull an item from the list and put it back, you can use a generic type for the function.

```
fun <T: Something?> duplicateFirstItemOfList(theList:MutableList<T>){
  theList.firstOrNull()?.let { theList.add(it) }
}
```

But I can't think of a way to create a function that would safely let you retrieve items from the list and also add Somethings to the list that you didn't retrieve from it.

Comment: Not enough reputation to upvote, but accepted the answer. Also Continuing the question Can I typecast a `List<Something?> original` to `MutableList<Something?>` while holding the same reference to `original` list in kotlin? (assuming original instance is mutable, but assigned to `List<>`)

Comment: Casting something doesn't change the reference. Casting is not a conversion--it only changes how the compiler treats the instance. It's generally a code smell to upcast something in order to mutate it. If the code that offered you a List downcast it from a MutableList, it's because that class's designer is trying to encapsulate the mutability internally. There is a convention that they can assume the list won't be mutated externally, so you could be breaking the code inside that class by messing with the list contents.

Comment: But how do we cast `List<Something?> original` to `MutableList<Something?>` ? 
 I tried,
```original as MutableList<Something?>``` throws compile time error.

Comment: What error did you get? Compile time errors are not thrown. They are simply logged and the IDE highlights them. Did you mean a runtime error was thrown?

Comment: Example of casting: https://pl.kotl.in/pKOIlHjK-